# generalChannel.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot, and I am trying to make it so that it would greet everyone when it turns on. I have been using `bot.channels.get` to find the channel and so far that part of the code works fine. It stops working when it tries to send a message.

I have tried all combinations of `bot.channels.get` and `bot.channels.find`, together with `generalChannel.send` and `generalChannel.sendMessage`, but to still no avail.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

let rawVariables = fs.readFileSync('variables.json');
let variables = JSON.parse(rawVariables);

var generalChannel;
bot.on('ready', () => {
  generalChannel = bot.channels.get(variables.Channels.general);
  generalChannel.send("Helllo!");
});

bot.login(variables.BotToken);
```

I just need it to message the channel when it starts up.

Comment: Are you sure that your channel is properly found by the 'get' method ? And are you sure this is a text channel ? Maybe you can try to add `console.log(generalChannel.type)` in your code to check if this is correct

Comment: what do you mean with "It stops working when it tries to send a message"? The node process stop? there are any stacktrace? Do you tried to add a .catch after the .send?

Comment: What is `variables.Channels.general` ? You should use the channel id instead of it's name.

Answer (score 0):

variables.Channels.general should be a string of the id of your channel

you can get the id by rightclicking on a channel -> copy id

it should look something like this:

```
'408632672669273'
```

Comment: variables.Channels.general is simply a json file containing all the information needed, like bottokens, channel ids etc. And yes, it is a string